# ContentAssistant for Editor in Eclipse RCP Project

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, xtext, content-assist

I'm building an Eclipse RCP and use an editor written with Xtext. The editor project is not developed by me so I can't just implement the `DSLProposalProvider`.

In my project I want to add some additional content assistant if a concrete model element is used in the editor. The editor offers no Extension Point to extend the `ProposalProvider`, so I'm looking for another possiblity.

I saw this [example](http://kofler.nonblocking.at/2013/07/extending-the-content-assist-capabilities-of-the-eclipse-xml-editor/), but it does not work, since I'm not using the XML editor and I can't match this way to my requirement. I currently have no idea how to go along with this problem and I'm sorry for this bad and unprecise description but I don't even know where to start so I'm open to any kind of help.

Comment: i dont understand why you dont simply implement `MyDslProposalProvider` in `yourdsl.ui`

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mention that the editor is not developed by myself, so I have no possibilty to make any changes inside the editor project. I will add this Information to my initial question.

Comment: what kind of proposals do you want to add

Comment: If the user uses an specific attribute from the DSL i want to provide him a list of strings which are imported from a database, so he don't have to look them up by himself and just add the string value to the attribute via content proposal.

Comment: xtext has zero hooks for that.

Comment: I came to the same solution. You maybe have some ideas to implement an assistent over the xtext editor? Something like "when this model element is created provide these proposals as value" with the eclipse way?

Comment: that would be normal implementation of MyDslProposalProvider, but you have to change the dsl for that

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the `org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.ContentProposalAdapter`class
You create an instance of this class that you'll attach to a `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text` component for example
To create an instance of `ContentProposalAdapter`you'll need to provide an instance of `TextContentAdapter`and `IContentProposalProvider` that will implement the logic of the content assist plus a few other things (ie what key will trigger the content assist etc)
[This page](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjface_fieldassist.htm) in the official eclipse documentation explains how to use those classes

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

In this usecase correct solution is to add proposals in `ProposalProvider` where you can give proposals based on the value entered in editor. You can also explore [scope provider](http://www.peterfriese.de/writing-xtext-scope-providers-with-xtend/) and check whether it will fit your usecase.